# Is Monero mining really as profitable practically as it is statistically?

Tags: mining

I am new to crypto mining in general and I don't understand how Monero mining can be so profitable?

Since mining a block takes 2 minutes I can mine 720 blocks in 24 hours. At it's current price and payout that's $1,008,000. Deducting electricity costs in India that's $300,000 to $500,000 of profit.

Is this just how profitable it is or is there a caveat?

Comment: massive massive caveats. you can't mine a block every 2 minutes unless you have more cpu power than all the other miners in the world combined.

Answer (score 1):

*Profit – a financial gain, especially the difference between the amount earned and the amount spent in buying, operating, or producing something. (source OED).*

Typically the biggest *operating* expense with mining any cryptocurrency is the cost of electricity (though this varies significantly by region). Typically the biggest *capital* expense is the mining hardware (in the case of Monero, computers). How much you *earn* will be driven by how fast the computers you run can hash (the more hashes you produce the more you'll *earn*).

Do the math based on these (including other expenses) and you get to your profitability.